# JQuery Replace Any Text in Element with New Text

Tags: jquery, replace, load

It's quite easy to find specific text with JQuery but I want to find any text within a specific element and replace it. I'm using load() to get an element from another page so the text will vary, that's why I can't rely on using :contains().

```
$("#results").load('http://www.test.com/url.html .ms-bodyareaframe .ms-vb-title a', function() {
    ('.ms-vb a').html("New Text");
});
```

The html of the element that's being loaded is:

```
<td class="ms-vb">
<a>
Old Text
</a>
</td>
```

It doesn't matter to me if the text replacement is done within the load using a function() or if it's done separately after the page is loaded. But I've tried several ways and I have not been able to get this to work.

Comment: I do not really understand what's your problem there.
This should work perfectly if you change `('.ms-vb a').html("New Text");` to `$('.ms-vb a').html("New Text");`, but I think that was just a typo.

Comment: Ouch what a glaring typo. I had tried a couple other methods to no avail so I was just frustrated. Thanks for picking up on that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can find and replace values in text nodes in a manageable manner:

```
function findAndReplace(elements, textToFind, textToPlace) {
    $.each(elements.contents(), function () {
        // This is added to make sure the nodes you request are text nodes
        if (this.nodeType == 3)
            this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(textToFind, textToPlace);
    });
}

findAndReplace($('your element(s)'), 'textToFind', 'textToPlace');
```